# django rest nested relation in post/put

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am new in django rest api developement. I have two models one is category and another is subcategories.
Here is my models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield()
    brief = models.TextField()
    subcategories = model.ManyToManyField('Subcategory', blank=True)
```

My serializer class

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title= serializer.Charfield()
    subcategories = Relatedfield(many=True)
```

Now in view

```
def post(self, request, format = None):
    data=request.DATA
    serialize= CategorySerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.valid():
        serializer.save()
```

How to save nested data like `{'title':"test",'subscategories':[{'description':'bla bla bla'},{'description':'test test'}]}` in post method.

I have read this in documentation

> Note: Nested serializers are only suitable for read-only
>   representations, as there are cases where they would have ambiguous or
>   non-obvious behavior if used when updating instances. For read-write
>   representations you should always use a flat representation, by using
>   one of the RelatedField subclasses.

Please let me suggest which is right way or solution to do nested relation post/put in django rest.

Comment: I need help regarding django rest framework(api) Posting data for m:m relationship and get added into database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating a `SubCategorySerializer` and adding this as a field on `CategorySerializer`?

```
class SubcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcategories = SubcategorySerializer(many=True)
```

Docs: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#nested-relationships