# django nested relation - many-to-many serialization

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, many-to-many

I have been struggling to add many-to-many relation in the django serializer than be accessed through the view.

I created 2 classes in the model file "MODISLevel1" & "FileProperties". Where MODISLevel1 has a field called "filesProperties" pointing to the "FileProperties" class.

The model looks like:

```
class FileProperties(models.Model):
    FileName = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    FileID = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    FileSize = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    Updated = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000) 
    GeoBox = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FileName

class Meta:
    ordering = ('FileName',)


class MODISLevel1(models.Model):

    ProductLevel = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                                  choices=ProductLevelsChoices,
                                  default='MOD03')

    SpacecraftType = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                  choices=SpacecraftTypeChoices,
                                  default='Terra')
    StartTimespan = models.TextField()
    EndTimespan = models.TextField()
    AOI = models.TextField()
    DegreeNumbers = models.TextField()

    filesProperties = models.ManyToManyField(FileProperties)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProductLevel

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ProductLevel',)
```

As for the serializer I checked http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#nested-relationships which tells that nested relationships should be created in the following way:

```
class FilePropertiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FileProperties
        fields = ('id', 'FileName', 'FileID', 'FileSize', 'Updated', 'GeoBox')

class MODISLevel1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    filesProperties = FilePropertiesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MODISLevel1
        fields = ('id', 'ProductLevel', 'SpacecraftType', 'StartTimespan', 'EndTimespan', 'AOI', 'DegreeNumbers', 'filesProperties')
```

for the the view file I tried different ways to make it work but with no success.

1-Creating an instance from the Model "MODISLevel1", filling its fields, saving it, then filling the m2m field through iteration:

```
modisLevel1 = MODISLevel1()
modisLevel1.ProductLevel = productLevel
modisLevel1.SpacecraftType = spacecraftType
modisLevel1.StartTimespan = startTimespan
modisLevel1.EndTimespan = endTimespan
modisLevel1.AOI = AOI
modisLevel1.DegreeNumbers = degreeNumbers
modisLevel1.save()

#Inside a loop
f = FileProperties()

f.FileID = fileID
f.FileName = fileName
f.Updated = updated
f.GeoBox = geoBox
f.FileSize = fileSize

f.save()

modisLevel1.filesProperties.add(f)

serializer = MODISLevel1Serializer(data=modisLevel1)


if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the error that i got is:
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data"
    ]
}
but for sure it's added in the database as I executed the save command "modisLevel1.save()", but that's not what I need.

2-Creating a json file and appending the 'filesProperties' to it through the iteration:

```
jsonFile = {u"ProductLevel": productLevel, u"SpacecraftType": spacecraftType, u"StartTimespan": startTimespan, 
    u"EndTimespan":endTimespan, u"AOI": AOI, u"DegreeNumbers": u"POINT(22.5,28.34) POINT(28.64,28.34) POINT(29.4,19.16) POINT(19.19,19.3067)", 
        u"filesProperties": [] }

#inside the loop
jsonFile["filesProperties"].append({u"FileName":fileName, u"FileID":fileID, u"FileSize":fileSize, u"Updated":updated, u"GeoBox":geoBox})

serializer = MODISLevel1Serializer(data=jsonFile)
```

and this one throws an error that the base model has to have a value before setting the m2m field:
Cannot add "": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"

3-Create a dict and parse the Model to this dictionary, and then convert the FileProperties to the dictionary and append it to the previously created one:

```
modisLevel1 = MODISLevel1()

modisLevel1.ProductLevel = productLevel
modisLevel1.SpacecraftType = spacecraftType
modisLevel1.StartTimespan = startTimespan
modisLevel1.EndTimespan = endTimespan
modisLevel1.AOI = AOI
modisLevel1.DegreeNumbers = degreeNumbers
modisLevel1.save()

dict = model_to_dict(modisLevel1)

#FIXME!
dict['filesProperties'] = [{"FileName": "fileName", "FileID": "fileID", "FileSize":     "fileSize", "Updated": "updated", "GeoBox": "geoBox"},
        {"FileName": "fileName", "FileID": "fileID", "FileSize": "fileSize", "Updated": "updated", "GeoBox": "geoBox"},
        {"FileName": "fileName", "FileID": "fileID", "FileSize": "fileSize", "Updated": "updated", "GeoBox": "geoBox"}]

serializer = MODISLevel1Serializer(data=dict)
```

and this one throws the same error as the previous one.

I did check some other posts that might be close to this issue, but none of them did work with me:
[django rest nested relation in post/put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146412/django-rest-nested-relation-in-post-put)

My json post request looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "ProductLevel": "MOD03",
        "SpacecraftType": "Terra",
        "StartTimespan": "2013.11.02",
        "EndTimespan": "2013.11.02",
        "AOI": "swath",
        "DegreeNumbers": "POINT(22.5,28.34) POINT(28.64,28.34) POINT(29.4,19.16)  POINT(19.19,19.3067)"
    }
]
```

Please notice that in the 'view.py' file I am able to store values in the database but if I bypass the serializer, like the examples that I've shown above.

So did somebody been through the same problem and know how to get this fixed? will be appreciated!